# How how to nest a model type in a model in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, model, nested

I have two models :

```
case class Exemple(
    f1: String,
    f2: List[Autre],
) extends ToJValue {
  implicit val formats: Formats = Exemple.formats

  override def toJValue: JValue = JObject(
    "f1"  -> JString(f1),
    "f2"  -> JArray(f2) ??????
  )
}
```

and

```
case class Autre(
    f3: String,
) extends ToJValue {
  implicit val formats: Formats = Autre.formats

  override def toJValue: JValue = JObject(
    "f3"  -> JString(f3),
  )
}
```

How can I define the Autre type in Exemple? JArray not working

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are `JValue` a custom type or a library?

Comment: What does `JArray` expects? Likely something like `Jarray(f2.map(_.toJValue))`

Comment: It's a custom type JValue. Gaël's method works. But I can't insert the values of Autre in Exemple

Comment: This looks like spray json. I suggest to see this page to see how they do it: https://github.com/spray/spray-json